# Auto Scrolling Collectionview cells using a timer

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

Im trying to autoscroll collection view cells every 5 seconds, so i created a timer and tried the following code :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BannerCell *cell = [self.bannerCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"bannerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //cell.isRoundImg = YES;
    [cell fillCellWithBanner:self.banners[indexPath.row]];
    NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger numberOfRecords = self.banners.count -1;
    if(rowIndex < numberOfRecords){
        rowIndex = (rowIndex + 1);
    }else {
        rowIndex = 0;
    }
    self.scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTimer:) userInfo:@{@"index" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)rowIndex]} repeats:YES];

    return cell;
}

-(void)startTimer:(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSString *indexString = timer.userInfo[@"index"];
    NSInteger indexRow = [indexString integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexRow);
   // [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.bannerCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexRow inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:NO];
  //  } completion:nil];
}
```

when i start the app, i works fine, but after about 30 seconds, everything goes wrong, the cells are been scrolled very fast, the timers function is been called about 10 times or more in 1 second.
anyone knows where the problem is?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method and use in viewDidLoad method

```
self.scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTimer:) userInfo:@{@"index" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)rowIndex]} repeats:YES];
```

timers function is been called about 10 times or more in 1 second

`cellForItemAtIndexPath` method is called multiple times. And it creates a new timer each time. If 10 timers are created then the cells will animate 10 times faster.

OR

Check whether `scrollingTimer` is already started or not like this in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
if (!scrollingTimer.isValid) {
    self.scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTimer:) userInfo:@{@"index" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)rowIndex]} repeats:YES];
}
```